# sed command removing whole text from file when using from python

Tags: python, shell, sed

I have to write a file using python, which I've done successfully. After some write operation on that file, I need to delete text matching some
strings(case insensative).

From executing the sed command I am getting the desired result but when using the same command from python deletes the whole content from the file.

I can not figure out what is going wrong with the script.

```
print ("working directory "+ os.getcwd()+'\n')

file = open ("testFile.txt","w")

for fileName in glob.glob('*.doc'):
    ## reading multiple doc files
    file.write () ## write to the file

cmd = "sed -i '/person/Id' ./testFile.txt"
os.system(cmd)
file.close()
```

This code is removing the whole text from the testFile.txt file.

When I execute the same sed command from the command line removes the line containing person from the testFile.txt.

```
sed -i '/person/Id' ./testFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command in the python script is being executed when your file handle (write mode) is still open. Try closing it first.

Note that executing the command-line `sed`, even from within python, doesn't require a file handle. sed will manage that itself.

Also, as Ken Hampson mentioned in the comments, it's better to use the [`with` construct](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for file reading/writing.

Comment: Agreed. Scoping the `open` in a `with` block would be a straightforward way to ensure that, no explicit close required.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to add but looking for the link via mobile isn't as quick as the desktop.